# Query window id from python in linux and mac

Tags: python, linux, macos, window, cross-platform

Is there any way to query window id by window name from python? Something that would work cross-platform perhaps (linux / mac)?
Or even better catch that id when starting a new window directly from os.sys ?

Answer (score 0):

Not on a cross-platform basis. While windows do have IDs on both Linux and Mac OS, the meaning of the IDs is quite different, as is what you can do with them. There's basically nothing in common between the two.

And no, you cannot get those IDs when you launch an application, as the window(s) aren't created until later.

Comment: Thanks duskwuff. I know I can use xwininfo on linux to query the id, what would I use on mac? I need the id to embedd the window into one of my qt ui's.

Comment: The [`CGWindowList...`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html) APIs will get you a list of windows, including the ID. You cannot use that to embed the window, though.

Comment: I've been trying to query the id number just like on linux (where it works just fine). After installing Quartz (making the X11 available to os x lion) I'm trying this `xwininfo -name "untitled" -int` but I keep getting errors _xwininfo: error: No window with name "untitled" exists!_ even though the _untitled_ window exists. I checked that via AppleScript and it seems to be there: `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get the title of every window of every process'`

Comment: Does anyone know what am I missing here?

Comment: `xwininfo` only works for X11 windows on Mac OS X. It does not work for native windows.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Is there any way to force a new window to open under X11? I want to get the id of an external text editor.

Comment: No. Ignore X11. It is completely irrelevant to the vast majority of Mac OS X applications.